# SQL insert from select statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

what i want the code to do is to take input from a text box ID number then it takes the record which the ID belongs to and insert it in another table but I changed the SQL Statement and still when I press the button nothing happens

```
Protected Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source= " & Server.MapPath("~/Members.mdb"))

Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

 Dim i As Integer

cmd.Connection = con

 cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text

cmd.CommandText = "insert into kfupm_stu_visitor (kfupm_stu_id, stu_name, kfupm_maj_id, kfupm_dep_id, level_id) select * from kfupm_stu where fupm_stu_id like @kfupm_stu_id"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("KFUPM_STU_ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = "%" & txtSTU_ID.Text & "%"
        con.Open()

        Try
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception

            Response.Redirect("msgpage.aspx?id=1")
        Finally
            con.Close()
            End Try

        Response.Redirect("msgpage.aspx?id=2")

    End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `VALUES`.  It should be `INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM table`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using a query to fill the columns, there's no need for the `values (...)` portion. It should just be:

```
insert into kfupm_stu_visitor 
(kfupm_stu_id, stu_name, kfupm_maj_id, kfupm_dep_id, level_id)
select * from 
kfupm_stu where fupm_stu_id like @kfupm_stu_id
```

Of course, that assumes that the columns in `kfupm_stu` match exactly the columns in the `insert into` list.

Comment: "Of course, that assumes that the columns in kfupm_stu match exactly the columns in the insert into list."  <== This.  The way the original query is written is very fragile.  If the schema for kfupm_stu changes, this statement ceases to work.  You should explicitly declare which columns you are SELECTing.